# LUIS rest api only returning one entity

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I'm new in using LUIS in azure and it's working fine so far. I've mapped an hierarchical entitiy (employee) with it's two children (firstname, lastname) to all utterances of an intents. So far so good. If I use the test tool on the upper right side of the LUIS gui I get the response I expect, the correct intent and the tow entities with it's values.

But now the problem: If I do the same via a rest call to the api, I get the same response, **only with one entity (firstname)** the second (lastname) is missing.

Here a screenshot of the test tool on the LUIS gui:

**Screenshot LUIS gui**

[image]

Here a screenshot of the response of the api:

**Screenshot API**

[image]

Is there any option I've to activate?

Comment: Which version of API are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now, I fixed it by deleting the intent and adding it again with new entity.